# how to make clang-format add new line before opening brace of a function?

Tags: coding-style, clang, clang-format

I'm interested in putting an opening brace for functions (but not if statements and other contexts). For example

```c++
void foo()
{
   ...
}
```

Flamewars aside, is there a good rationale for *not* doing this? Although I use same-line open-brackets for if/else and smaller blocks, I think in this case visual organization of larger units of code (functions/methods/classes/structs) can trump perfect consistency.

Moreover, how do I get clang-format to follow this style?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) says, invoke `clang-format` with `-style=file`, and use a `.clang-format` file placed in an enclosing directory to customize style options. The format style option specifying brace placement is called `BreakBeforeBraces`. From the docs,

> **BreakBeforeBraces** (`BraceBreakingStyle`)

The brace breaking style to

> use.
>
> Possible values:
>
> - `BS_Attach` (in configuration: `Attach`) Always attach braces to surrounding context.
> - `BS_Linux` (in configuration: `Linux`) Like `Attach`, but break before braces on function, namespace and class definitions.
> - `BS_Stroustrup` (in configuration: `Stroustrup`) Like `Attach`, but break before function definitions, and ‘else’.
> - `BS_Allman` (in configuration: `Allman`) Always break before braces.
> - `BS_GNU` (in configuration: `GNU`) Always break before braces and add an extra level of indentation to braces of control statements, not to
>   those of class, function or other definitions.

The style that matches your description is `BS_Stroustrup`. Add the following entry to your `.clang-format`

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Stroustrup
```

In addition to the docs, [clang.llvm.org](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#breakbeforebraces) lists all the options and illustrates many of them with examples.

Comment: great thanks. As an aside, what's Bjarne's rationale for making an exception for "else"?

Comment: `Stroustrup` is best choice. +1

Comment: I like StrouStrup but I need braces of empty func on same line

Comment: Strangely inflexible. I want a break before else, but not before opening brace of function. So between "Attach" and "Stroustrup". Very annoying.

Comment: @JaapVersteegh Now (but possibly not in 2015) you can set `BraceBreakingStyle` to `Custom` and set every individual flag in `BraceWrapping` to your preference

Answer (score 36):

Pradhan has an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29504889/527489), but you may find that you get breaks where you do not want them (as I found).

There is another option, "Custom", in at least clang-format versions 3.8 and 5 (I'm using 3.8 and found BS_Custom in the 5 docs).  With this, you can specify in BraceWrapping what you want, including an "AfterFunction" option.

In the following example excerpt, I have listed others as true/false since the OP's question only specifies AfterFunction (i.e. "before opening brace of a function"):

```
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true/false
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true/false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true/false
  AfterStruct:     true/false
  AfterUnion:      true/false
  BeforeCatch:     true/false
  BeforeElse:      true/false
  IndentBraces:    true/false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
```

I have tested this with my configuration and it gives finer-grained control of brace breaking.